# How to create a list as below picture?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

[A setting picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItIIS.png)

How to do that in android?

Before I used to referencescreen but it could'n use icon for each item.

Comment: Have you tried ListView ?

Comment: ListVIew with CoustemAdapter in android

Comment: For witchbutton at 5 postition. How to do that.

Comment: What do you mean? Can you clarify please

Comment: switch button android at 5th in listviewItem. You see that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ListView` with `CustomAdapter` for doing this.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView lv_applicationlist;
ApplicationListingAdapter adapter;
ArrayList<Integer> app_image=new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> app_name=new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lv_applicationlist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_applicationlist);

    app_name.add("Camera");
    app_name.add("Gallery");
    app_name.add("Send");
    app_name.add("Share");

    app_image.add(R.drawable.ic_menu_camera);
    app_image.add(R.drawable.ic_menu_gallery);
    app_image.add(R.drawable.ic_menu_send);
    app_image.add(R.drawable.ic_menu_share);

    adapter = new ApplicationListingAdapter(MainActivity.this, app_name,app_image);
    lv_applicationlist.setAdapter(adapter);

  }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lv_applicationlist"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

ApplicationListingAdapter.java

```
public class ApplicationListingAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
ArrayList<String> app_name;
ArrayList<Integer> app_image;

public ApplicationListingAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<String> application_name, ArrayList<Integer> application_image) {

    activity = a;
    app_name = application_name;
    app_image = application_image;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)     activity.getSystemService(activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

public int getCount() {
    return app_name.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public static class ViewHolder {

    public TextView tv_appname;
    public ImageView iv_appicon;
    public Switch mySwitch;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    View vi = convertView;

    if (convertView == null) {
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.application_list_row, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.tv_appname = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tv_appname);
        holder.iv_appicon = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.iv_appicon);
        holder.mySwitch = (Switch) vi.findViewById(R.id.mySwitch);

        vi.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
    }
    holder.tv_appname.setText(app_name.get(position));
    holder.iv_appicon.setImageResource(app_image.get(position));

    if(app_name.get(position).equals("Send"))
    {
        holder.mySwitch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else{
        holder.mySwitch.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    return vi;
   }
}
```

application_list_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_appicon"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_appname"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_margin="10dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Store App"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

  <Switch
    android:id="@+id/mySwitch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Output will be look like this :

[image]

Comment: I know create a custom listview but. In "send item" it has a switch button

Comment: Easiest method is, add a Switch in application_list_row.xml and set its visibility as Gone. And in the adapter class, set the visibility of Switch as Visible in the position where you want. Please check the edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

It is a simple Listview. Refer the following code and replace the `list_row` with the list row design .xml that you want. This should help.

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    View row;
    public static List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    Context context;

    class ViewHolder {
        ImageView ivShare;
    }

    public ListAdapter(Context context, List<String> _list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = _list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    ViewHolder holder;

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.ivShare = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.iv_share);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.ivShare.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }
}
```